# how to use vectors of dataframe in for loop make it dynamic

Tags: r, for-loop

I wanted to check all datatype of the vectors in `data.frame` in `R` and print the result

```
sar=c(1:10)
dsj=c(11:20)
dev=c(21:30)

gfs=data.frame(sar,dsj,dev)

for (x in colnames(gfs)) {

  print(x)
print(is.numeric(gfs$"dev"))

#here I am unable to use x as reference to column names 
print(is.numeric(gfs$x))

}

# here I am unable to use x as reference to column names 

print(is.numeric(gfs$x))
```

How can I check the datatypes of all the vectors in `data.frame`, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You cant use `$`-subsetting if your column name is stored in a variable. Use `[[` instead

Comment: Thanks a lot it works

Answer (score 1):

You can use lapply to apply a function to each column of a dataframe. Here are two ways to implement it to find the class of each column, or to find whether they are of class numeric:

```
> lapply(gfs, class)
$sar
[1] "integer"

$dsj
[1] "integer"

$dev
[1] "integer"

> lapply(gfs, is.numeric)
$sar
[1] TRUE

$dsj
[1] TRUE

$dev
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help